# Resharper says to convert foreach to LINQ, but is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Project entity that has a navigational property which is a list of Addresses. On a search page I allow the user to search for projects by several addresses at a time. Is it possible to do this in a single statement or do I need to loop though the searched addresses?

Currently I have the following code where searchedAddresses is a list of addresses used to search for a project. In the foreach loop, I create a query and union it with the overall query each time through the loop. Resharper is saying the foreach can be rewritten using LINQ and I'd like to get rid of the unioning of queries if possible.

```
foreach (AddressModel address in searchedAddresses)
{
    var query = _projectRepository.Get().Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => a.StreetName.ToLower().StartsWith(address.StreetName.ToLower())));

    union = (union == null ? query : union.Union(query));
}
```

I've tried to write it as one statement, but it does not work:

```
var query = _projectRepository.Get().Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => searchedAddresses.Any(sa => a.StreetName.ToLower().StartsWith(sa.StreetName.ToLower())));
```

When doing this I get the following error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'EPIC.WebAPI.Models.AddressModel'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I'm assuming this is because of the searchedAddresses.Any() part. Does anyone know how to write this query so that I don't need to loop through the addresses and union the queries? Or is this an OK thing to do?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added the ToLower and StartsWith to the second query which I initially forgot.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the simplest approach is to create a `List<string>` for the street names you're searching for first - I would expect those to be convertible:

```
var searchedStreets = searchedAddresses.Select(x => x.StreetName).ToList();
var query = projectRepository
      .Get()
      .Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => searchStreets.Contains(a.StreetName)));
```

If a `List<string>` doesn't work, it's probably worth trying a `string[]`. (Just change `ToList` to `ToArray`.)

Comment: And of course if `searchedAddresses` happens to be an `IQueryable` from the same context then you can remove the `ToList`, have a *single* database round trip, and still have a working query.  Probably even a more efficient one at that.  Of course, if `searchedAddreses` isn't a query from the same context, then this is the best you can do.

Comment: I think I simplified my example too much. I am matching above based on just StreetName, but really I want to match according to StreetName, StreetNumber, and ZipCode, which does not allow me to use the searchStreets.Contains() approach.

Comment: @Bumper: It's not clear what you mean - if you want to match on *any* of those things, then you could have three different arrays and use `x.Contains(...) || y.Contains(...) || z.Contains(...)`. But yes, it does sound like you've simplified too much :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect ReSharper wants you to do something like this:

```
var union = searchedAddresses
    .Select(address => _projectRepository.Get()
        .Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a =>
            a.StreetName.ToLower().StartsWith(address.StreetName.ToLower()))))
    .Aggregate(
        (something)null,
        (union, query) => union.Union(query));
```

where `something` is the same type as `union` is in your original code.

(If it's telling you that you cna convert the loop to a single query, it should give you the option to do it automatically too.)

I don't see that as particularly cleaner myself.

Comment: I did not know resharper could do it for me. Now I do. Thanks.

Comment: This post, just like Aravol's has the problem in that it ends up executing a query for each address, unlike Jon's solution that executes just one query, total.

Comment: @Servy: When I use this method, I see only one query that unions together all the addresses being searched.

Comment: @Servy I'm just replicating what ReSharper wants to do. ReSharper isn't as good as Jon :)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you have to "uinion" all results for a given collection like that, you can replace the Foreach with a [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement;

```
searchedAddresses
    .SelectMany(address =>
        _projectRepository
        .Get()
        .Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => 
            a.StreetName
            .ToLower()
            .StartsWith(address.StreetName.ToLower()))))
    .Distinct();
```

This will iterate over each result, giving the same effect (with a likely performance boost) over union-ing each individual subquery

EDIT: Used the wrong lambda parameter when I copy/pasted your problem's code. Fixed that.
EDIT: SelectMany does not remove duplicates, unlike Union, so I updated the code accordingly

Comment: This will still execute a query against the database for each address though, unless `searchedAddresses` is an `IQueryable` from the same context.

Comment: `Union` removes duplicates; `SelectMany` does not.

Comment: @Rawling that part I was not aware of, will update the answer accordingly